# How play multiple audio files located on smartphone through Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, audio, android

When I connect my LG Optimus F3Q to my Windows 7 PC, it connects in "Media sync (MTP)" mode. I can get into the file structure of the phone and its SD card through Windows Explorer and double click individual mp3 files to play them. But there's no clear way to play, say, an entire folder, or select a group of songs and play them all. Is this possible, and if so, how?

This question actually comes from trying to work around an [ongoing issue while playing music on my phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/108434/how-to-prevent-firefox-from-killing-music) I have.

Comment: Holding CTRL and/or SHIFT to select multiple MP3 files doesn't work? What happens if you drag one of the folders onto Windows Media Player?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Yes, I can select multiple files, but the option to "play all" in the right-click context menu doesn't exist. In Windows Media Player, if I select multiple items from the File menu, it says "cannot play multiple items".

Comment: Did you try dragging the folder or multiple files onto WMP as @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 suggested?

Comment: @Karan Yes, it won't let me add them to a playlist, individually or as a group.

Answer (score 0):

Fun issue, had to plug in my phone to check this out,

Solution : 
In Windows 10 x64 after having VLC installed, I was able to highlight multiple media files on a connected MTP device, right click, and click "Add to VLC Media Player's Playlist". 
This should work on Windows 7 as well so long as the right click context is added.

Explanation :
MTP is a virtualized file structure, and not an actual one. Unlike having the file system exposed in the way a flash drive does, whenever you use MTP it sends the requests to the phone to work with the filesystem. You could think of this as if everything you're seeing was shortcuts pointing to the data elsewhere.
Due to this, some programs like Windows Media Player don't work quite the same with them.